# Xamarin Forms app Displays fine in UWP and Android but NOT on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an application that takes input from Json API, deserialize it using Newtonsoft.Json library, then binds it to ListView using datatemplate.

The application works perfectly fine on UWP and Android but on iOS it shows blank screen. I have not changed anything in the iOS side.

Here's what my xaml file looks like. Is there anything else I should do in order to show my list?

** I have the latest update of all packages and I deployed the application to the simulator AND my phone with no use.

```
 <ListView x:Name="SoftTopicsListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Topics}"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                  IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"/>
                            <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ShortDescription}" FontSize="11" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Please help me,

Regards,  Omar.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors

Comment: Is your data service using SSL? Btw, I remember when I ported my App from Windows/Android to iOS ItemSelected had to be replaced with ItemTapped, among other things.

Comment: @JanAndersen it doesn't use SSL, it's a normal JSON api I coded using Razor Pages. I looked into the sample tabbed page provided by Visual Studio and it works normally with almost the same code! I don't really know and this issue is making me crazy.

Comment: iOS are all about security.. If you don't use SSL you need to add the JSON source to a white-list of some sort.

Comment: @JanAndersen That was the solution! Thanks man. I changed my links to HTTPS and followed the guide to add exception for untrusted urls and all worked perfectly. I owe you my life.